# Avoid WebDav requests on request for downloading .doc file

Tags: ms-word, webdav, download

We have WebDAV activated on our server. And when we try to make a download of a word file from the server with the content-type "application/msword" a WebDAV authentication popup is shown. I do not want this popup. The file should just be downloaded and opened without

The only way I can avoid this, is giving it content-type "application/octet-stream".

Is that the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the content type should stay what it is, correctly indicating the type.

The popup likely comes from Microsoft Office, which tries to open the document in read/write mode. I think it depends on the Office version how this works exactly, and how it could be disabled (so you'll probably can find the answer somewhere on MSDN).

Comment: That seems right to keep the type description. But the popup is a disturbance to the users, who know nothing about, what is happening. And I have no control over their environments. I can see that Word sends two requests to the server, and if the reponse to these are Not implemented, then the popup will not come up. Could there maybe a way to turn off WebDAV for certain requests?